# Reversing tokens from strtok results in empty string

Tags: c, parsing, pointers, c-strings, strtok

I am attempting to reverse the words/tokens returned from strtok, I am iterating over each token in reverse order and assigning each ith value to a buffer called `new`. I can print each ith value/char of the token pointer `p` but for some reason I am having trouble assigning the chars `p` is pointing to the buffer `new`. What am I missing or doing wrong here?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    char str[] = "This is an example!";
    char *new = malloc(strlen(str));
    char *p = strtok(str, " ");
    size_t j = 0;
    while (1) {
        for (size_t i=strlen(p)-1; i>-1; i--) {
            new[j++] = p[i];
        }
        p = strtok(NULL, " ");
        if (!p)
            break;
        new[j++] = ' ';
    }
    printf("%s\n", new);
    return 0;
}
```

stdout:

Intended/expected output:

```
sihT si na !elpmaxe
```

Comment: Try: `i=strlen(p)` -> `i=strlen(p)-1`. Because `p[strlen(p)]` is a `NUL` character (put there by `strtok`). Be sure to also check for empty strings.

Comment: Seems it doesn't fix unfortunately.

Comment: But do you understand that that is a problem? So even if it does not fix all the problems do you agree/understand it needs to change?

Comment: Yes I do thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Terminating null-character will be added to the buffer `new` because the initial value of the loop is `strlen(p)`. It should be `strlen(p)-1`.
- The type of `i` should be `ssize_t` (signed type) instead of `size_t` (unsigned type) to have `i>-1` work well.
- One more byte should be allocated for `new` and terminating null-character should be added at the end of string.

Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    char str[] = "This is an example!";
    char *new = malloc(strlen(str)+1); /* allocate one more byte */
    char *p = strtok(str, " ");
    size_t j = 0;
    while (1) {
        for (ssize_t i=strlen(p)-1; i>-1; i--) { /* fix loop */
            new[j++] = p[i];
        }
        p = strtok(NULL, " ");
        if (!p)
            break;
        new[j++] = ' ';
    }
    new[j] = '\0'; /* add terminating null-character */
    printf("%s\n", new);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This works thank you for explaining! I am new to c strings and this helped me tremendously!

Comment: I attempted every method except the ssize_t change.